# Help! Can't boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and I'm facing this current issue.

So.. yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit via live USB formatted it everything reading this manual anyway the installation went all smooth, but when I tried to boot windows I could not see it in grub2.

**The only options I had were:**

Ubuntu

Advanced options for Ubuntu

efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi

EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi sda7

I went ahead and also performed a boot-repair it gave me this printed summary below but also saying that I should "Make BIOS boot from sda7/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi whatever that means. Below is the url summary.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated!!

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13297517/

Comment: Well, you deleted Windows. Boot-Repair states that Linux is the only OS on your machine. You'll have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Please try the answer in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/a/695757/283721)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, gone...
Did you choose this option when installing ?

[image: http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/e/ec/Install-Ubuntu-Linux-Step-7Bullet1.jpg/900px-Install-Ubuntu-Linux-Step-7Bullet1.jpg]

Comment: Based on the partitions in the Boot Repair output, it looks like DarkRogue83 selected the "Something Else" option and partitioned the disk manually, but accidentally deleted Windows along the way. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to recover. [This question and answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) covers the dilemma in more detail

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can't boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu 14.04, so ... What's the problem?

Jokes aside;) UEFI is a headhache. Perhaps you find some clues in this IMHO excellent AskUbuntu post.  -->
[How can I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on a UEFI HP notebook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/666631/how-can-i-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-on-a-uefi-hp-notebook)

Comment: Windows is gone from the disk. This has nothing to do with UEFI; it was a partitioning error at (or possibly before) installation time.

Comment: Ops thankfully i backed uo my data before that and my only loss are my bookmarks and my adobe suite oh well not a big loss.

Comment: I sort of figured by now that it was something like that thanks for replies everyone! Thankfully i backed up my data before. What have i done to delete windows i dont remember deleting anything all i did was partion sections? Or could this have been an error of some?

Comment: We'd need to watch a video of what you did to know with certainty what the error was. I'm guessing you didn't make such a video, so it's basically just speculative now. Chances are you misinterpreted what an option was and deleted a partition by mistake. One bug is a serious contender, though: When libparted (which Ubuntu's installer uses for partitioning) sees something it doesn't like, the disk often shows up as unpartitioned. If this happened and it didn't set off alarm bells in your head, you might have created partitions that overwrote the originals without realizing there was a problem.