# Is there a way to remove grub without a live cd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had installed Puppy Tahr alongside with Ubuntu 14.04,then I had do remove Puppy but the grub still remained installed.

And even now,grub menu appears everytime I turn the computer on,showing the removed distro/partition and asks me to choose a one to boot with.

How can I remove it without using a live cd(I don't have it). 
Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: If it's fully removed, have you tried `sudo update-grub` from the terminal?

Comment: I've not tried it yet,I don't know many of linux commands,I think I show give it a try ,thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. It's all good that the other person got credit for it. I don't do it for the points and they took the time to explain what it did, how it did it, and why it did it so it's good that you got it squared away. Another application to look into (though it needs to be run from a Live USB/DVD) is `Boot Repair` which you can read about [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) if you want. You can also see a [prior answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/695754/grub-not-recognizing-windows-10/695757#695757) that covers this in a bit of detail and is related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo update-grub` should do it. The grub menu is automatically generated based on configuration files and the current partition layout. Be warned thought that if anything goes wrong you won't be able to boot unless you know what you are doing at the GRUB prompt. Having a Live CD or grub boot disk handy would be a good idea.